# KDE after update to 5.24 transparency on conky not working

Tags: kde, plasma, conky, mint, transparency

After updating to KDE 5.24, conky transparency windows were showing with black background.  How do I fix this?

I have the following setup:
Linux Mint 20.3
KDE Plasma Version: 5.68.0
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel 5.4.0-135-generic
OS Type 64-bit

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; and the default KDE Plasma is set for each release of Kubuntu/Ubuntu.  If your *update* was using the Kubuntu-backports; why not just tell us.  What OS/release are you using? and why tag an off-topic OS?  (*or how does the Xfce Mint themes apply?*)

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Answer (score 1):

I found a post that advised "Shift+Alt+F12 should toggle the compositor."

Post reference: KDE after update not working transparency on conky this was with a user using ArchLinux.

This spoke of an issue with the compositor needing to be reset. "Shift+Alt+F12" did not do this for me, but this article is pointing to an issue with the compositor in ArchLinux, so I went to settings and typed in compositor, and that brought up a settings window for the compositor.

There is a checkbox that says "allow applications to block compositing", I unchecked that and my transparent windows immediately went transparent.

Conky transparent windows are now working.

Note: this is a way to fix the issue, fixes are hard to find, fighting over versions, helps few.  Linux Mint and KDE are modified of versions of Ubuntu.  I am simply offering a fix to help an issue that others are having.

PS: I have posted this in LinuxMint Forums, too.
[[Solved] After recent updates, involving Mint and KDE 5.24 Conky window transparency stops working](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2324983#p2324983)

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: SE *Unix & Linux* provides Linux support which of course include Linux Mint and KDE Plasma. This is an official Ubuntu support site; which can be accessed via your Ubuntu SSO, or alternatively via Stack Exchange too  (*to access CHAT you'll need to login to stack exchange*)